# Counterexample to the primality test

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, primality-test

This is a generalization of [this claim](https://mathoverflow.net/q/286304/88804) .

Can you provide a counterexample to the following claim?

> Let $n$ be a natural number greater than two .  Let $r$ be the smallest odd prime number such that $r \nmid n$ and $n^2 \not\equiv 1 \pmod r$ . Let $P_n^{(a)}(x)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot\left(\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+a}\right)^n+\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+a}\right)^n\right)$ , where $a$ is a nonzero integer coprime to $n$ . Then $n$ is a prime number if and only if $P_n^{(a)}(x) \equiv x^n \pmod {x^r-1,n}$ .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNjlEKwjAMht93iiEIyVZhnY8xR_AKwtSJZWsaasWJenfLRPElJB9f_kR4banoOBcN412Cd90I3uyRH9pkrJYnGril29mNPQwb9ka5raZKbb2vtKGs6ewpDXWNFPt0jQKK9Coir6n4bG7DEcREZG7K57Mc3Sn92K7N2JYmsvRT0uh8D7G2iFS402zB33diOsQlTLu4smgEV5B7-REs8wmTQyTBYs5a4Hc8BK_h4lJGSG_TqUzR&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

I have tested this claim for many random values of $n$ and $a$ and there were no counterexamples .

**EDIT**

[Algorithm implementation in PARI/GP](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVUNtqwzAMfc9XaIUWO3gQpw9jePqEfkFIIGwJBGo5KC64rN23T2lC1j1JR5ejo0No39-OLmvRuiz5Nio2pAGhKvNkoHVgDRR1fgpfyprU8KvVKyDtssm353M3RVak8XvoFSFauN2A9iViYYC7eGFShdauDzzy4DvFQn80EILxV3VB2rN2Qw-SYgGHAzB8AP1bfXRflq5Eu0YRs42xlrl75q_DtFyZBQn_fOxZ5UImVYQ_eTTDUnqykEbZ2JxoKK-SsfWPdmmsynoenN9PmwmrKQ3JdTHgWYCRhKLaPfBug5_Bj2EaopS0-wUL9HIv&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) without directly computing $P_n^{(a)}(x)$.

I have verified this claim for $n \in [3,100000]$ with $a \in [-100,100]$  .

Comment: The question above indicates $a$ is an integer coprime to $n$, whereas the Sage code uses $a=1$, so is $a=1$ sufficient? The question above indicates $n^2\not\equiv 1\,(mod\, r)$, whereas the Sage code uses "lift(Mod(n,r)^2)==1" as a condition for continuing the search for a suitable value of $r$. I'm not familary with Sage, but is the lift function really necessary?

Comment: @StevenClark You can use any other value of $a$ which is coprime to $n$ . I put $a=1$ because condition $\operatorname{gcd}(a,n)=1$ is always fulfilled for that value of $a$. In PARI/GP powermod is implemented via lift function, i.e. `powermod(n,2,r)=lift(Mod(n,r)^2)` .

Comment: @PeđaTerzić Congrats on coming up with a practical test! How is the progress on the primality test? Thanks for the code too, I plan to use it on some of my multi-thousand digit probable primes.

Comment: @PeđaTerzić also wanted to ask what is the running time of the code you produced (a 4000-digit input took 2 minutes for me).

Comment: @J.Linne $O(\log^3 n) $

Answer (score 10):

The claim is true.

---

It is true that if $n$ is a prime number, then $P_n^{(a)}(x)\equiv x^n\pmod{x^r-1,n}$.

*Proof* :

We have, by the binomial theorem,
$$\begin{align}P_n^{(a)}(x)&=\frac 12\left(\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+a}\right)^n+\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+a}\right)^n\right)
\\\\&=\frac 12\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom nix^{n-i}\bigg(\bigg(-\sqrt{x^2+a}\bigg)^i+\bigg(\sqrt{x^2+a}\bigg)^i\bigg)
\\\\&=\sum_{j=0}^{(n-1)/2}\binom{n}{2j}x^{n-2j}(x^2+a)^j
\\\\&=x^n+\sum_{j=1}^{(n-1)/2}\binom{n}{2j}x^{n-2j}(x^2+a)^j\end{align}$$
Since $\binom nm\equiv 0\pmod n$ for $1\le m\le n-1$, there exists a polynomial $f$ with integer coefficients such that 
$$P_n^{(a)}(x)=x^n+0\times (x^r-1)+nf$$
from which
$$P_n^{(a)}(x)\equiv x^n\pmod{x^r-1,n}$$
follows.$\quad\blacksquare$

---

It is true that if $P_n^{(a)}(x)\equiv x^n\pmod{x^r-1,n}$, then $n$ is a prime number.

*Proof* :

Suppose that $n$ is an even number. Then, there exist a polynomial $f$ with integer coefficients and an integer $s$ such that$$P_n^{(a)}(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2i}x^{n-2i}(x^2+a)^i=x^n+s(x^r-1)+nf$$
Considering $[x^{n}]$ where $[x^k]$ denotes the coefficient of $x^k$ in $P_n^{(a)}(x)$, we get
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2i}\equiv 1\pmod n,$$
i.e.
$$2^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod n$$which is impossible.

So, $n$ has to be an odd number.

There exist a polynomial $\displaystyle g=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ix^i$ where $a_i$ are integers and an integer $t$ such that

$$P_n^{(a)}(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{(n-1)/2}\binom n{2j}x^{n-2j}(x^2+a)^j=x^n+t(x^r-1)+ng$$

Considering $[x^0]$, we have
$$0=-t+na_0\implies t=na_0$$
So, we see that there exists a polynomial $h$ with integer coefficients such that
$$P_n^{(a)}(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{(n-1)/2}\binom n{2j}x^{n-2j}(x^2+a)^j=x^n+nh\tag1$$

It follows that $[x^k]\equiv 0\pmod n$ for all $k$ such that $0\le k\le n-1$.

Now, $(1)$ can be written as

$$P_n^{(a)}(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{(n-1)/2}\sum_{k=0}^{j}\binom n{2j}\binom jkx^{n-2(j-k)}a^{j-k}=x^n+nh$$

So, we see that 
$$\begin{align}&[x^3]\equiv 0\pmod n
\\\\&\implies \left(\binom n{n-3}\binom {(n-3)/2}0+\binom n{n-1}\binom {(n-1)/2}1\right)a^{(n-3)/2}\equiv 0\pmod n
\\\\&\implies \binom n{n-3}\equiv 0\pmod n\end{align}$$
since $\gcd(a,n)=1$.

Also, we have
$$\begin{align}&[x^5]\equiv 0\pmod n
\\\\&\implies \bigg(\binom n{n-5}\binom {(n-5)/2}0+\binom n{n-3}\binom {(n-3)/2}1
\\&\qquad\qquad+\binom n{n-1}\binom {(n-1)/2}2\bigg)a^{(n-5)/2}\equiv 0\pmod n
\\\\&\implies \binom n{n-5}\equiv 0\pmod n\end{align}$$
So, we can get (one can prove by induction)
$$\begin{align}&[x^3]\equiv [x^5]\equiv [x^7]\equiv\cdots\equiv [x^{n-2}]\equiv 0\pmod n
\\\\&\implies\binom n{n-3}\equiv\binom n{n-5}\equiv\binom n{n-7}\equiv\cdots\equiv\binom{n}{2}\equiv 0\pmod n
\\\\&\implies\binom{n}{2}\equiv \binom{n}{3}\equiv \binom n4\cdots \equiv\binom n{n-2}\equiv 0\pmod n\tag2\end{align}$$

Suppose here that $\displaystyle n=\prod_{i=1}^mp_i^{b_i}$ is a composite number where $p_1\lt p_2\lt\cdots\lt p_m$ are primes and $b_i$ are positive integers.

Let $[[N]]$ be the number of prime factor $p_i$ in $N$.

Then, we have the followings :

- $[[1!]]=[[2!]]=\cdots =[[(p_i-1)!]]=0$
- $[[p_i!]]=1$
- $[[(n-1)!]]=[[(n-2)!]]=\cdots =[[(n-p_i)!]]$

Using these, we see that
$$\binom n1=\frac{n!}{1!(n-1)!}=n,\binom n2=\frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!},\cdots, \binom{n}{p_i-1}=\frac{n!}{(p_i-1)!(n-(p_i-1))!}$$
are divisible by $p_i^{b_i}$, and that 
$$\binom n{p_i}=\frac{n!}{p_i!(n-p_i)!}$$
is not divisible by $p_i^{b_i}$.

Therefore, we see that $$\binom n1=\frac{n!}{1!(n-1)!}=n,\binom n2=\frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!},\cdots, \binom{n}{p_1-1}=\frac{n!}{(p_1-1)!(n-(p_1-1))!}$$
are divisible by $n$, and that $$\binom{n}{p_1}=\frac{n}{p_1!(n-p_1)!}$$ is not divisible by $n$, which contradicts $(2)$.

It follows that $n$ is a prime number.$\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: If the proof you gave were correct that would be a significant breakthrough in theory of primality testing.

Comment: In $P_n^{(a)}(x)=x^n+s(x^r-1)+nf$, why is $s$ necessarily an integer and not a polynomial of higher degree?