# Compositeness test using $S_k=2S_{k-1}-3S_{k-2}+2S_{k-3}$ recurrence relation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples

Can you prove or disprove the following claim:

> Let $S_k=2S_{k-1}-3S_{k-2}+2S_{k-3}$ with $S_0=0$ , $S_1=1$ , $S_2=1$ . Let $n$ be an odd natural number greater than $2$. Let $\left(\frac{D}{n}\right)$ be the [Jacobi symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol) where $D$ represents the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial $x^3-2x^2+3x-2$, and let $\delta(n)=n-\left(\frac{D}{n}\right)$ , then:
>   $$\text{If } n \text{ is a prime then } S_{\delta(n)} \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$$

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw1jcEKgzAQRO9-Resp0RU0XgrbPfVcUP-gakqDMZGspZTSf29y6GVgZt4wjlrMgp7ECh30MEj6cE01ckMNsopiI_F6GKuFPdMKTF3BquwLbsqh4EjWxE3iWaUBoy1LiUHvz-AES_xmM7lqCd7padFBVOoETmJm7uLqZ5G-Z1BQtaBkLIhq2IJxu8i74MfbaN-H6Fd9zOW_uPh182z2lEn8AdrGOlg=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==). Note that $D=-28$ .

I have verified this claim for all $n$ up to $200000$ . I was searching for counterexample using the following PARI/GP code:

```
rec(m,P,Q,R)={s0=0;s1=1;s2=1;l=3;while(l<=m,s=P*s2+Q*s1+R*s0;s0=s1;s1=s2;s2=s;l++);return(s);}
RPT(n1,n2)={forprime(n=n1,n2,d=n-kronecker(-28,n);if(Mod(rec(d,2,-3,2),n)!=0,print(n);break))}
```

P.S.

Wolfram Alpha gives the following closed form for $S_k$ : $$S_k=\frac{i2^{-k} \cdot \left(\left(1-i\sqrt{7}\right)^k-\left(1+i\sqrt{7}\right)^k\right)}{\sqrt{7}}$$

Comment: I see... https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286304/chebyshev-polynomials-of-the-first-kind-and-primality-testing

Comment: What is $28$? The discriminant of the polynomial $x^3-3x^2+2x-2$?

Comment: @user158834 $-28$ is the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial $x^3-2x^2+3x-2$

Comment: @WillJagy https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3266369

Comment: It would be easier to understand the qiestion if you explain where -28 came from and what Jacobi symbol has to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is true.

*Proof* :

Since the roots of $x^3-2x^2+3x-2=0$ are $x=1,\frac{1\pm i\sqrt 7}{2}$, there exist $A,B,C$ such that
$$S_k=A\bigg(\frac{1-i\sqrt 7}{2}\bigg)^k+B\bigg(\frac{1+i\sqrt 7}{2}\bigg)^k+C\cdot 1^k$$
Using $S_0=0,S_1=S_2=1$, we get $A=\frac{i}{\sqrt 7},
B=\frac{-i}{\sqrt 7}$ and $C=0$ to have
$$S_k=\frac{i}{\sqrt 7}\bigg(\frac{1-i\sqrt 7}{2}\bigg)^k-\frac{i}{\sqrt 7}\bigg(\frac{1+i\sqrt 7}{2}\bigg)^k\tag1$$

- **Case 1** : $n=7$
  Since $\left(\frac{-28}{7}\right)=0$, we get
  $$S_{\delta(7)}=S_7=7\equiv 0\pmod 7$$
- **Case 2** : $n$ is a prime satisfying either $n\equiv 1,2$ or $4\pmod 7$
  Since $\left(\frac n7\right)=1$, we get
  $$\bigg(\frac{-28}{n}\bigg)=\bigg(\frac{-1}{n}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{2^2}{n}\bigg)\bigg(\frac 7n\bigg)=(-1)^{(n-1)/2}\cdot 1\cdot \frac{(-1)^{3(n-1)/2}}{\left(\frac n7\right)}=1$$So, we have, using $(1)$,
  $$\begin{align}2^{n+2}S_{\delta(n)}&=2^{n+2}S_{n-1}
  \\\\&=\frac{i}{\sqrt 7}\bigg((1+i\sqrt 7)\left(1-i\sqrt{7}\right)^{n}-(1-i\sqrt 7)\left(1+i\sqrt{7}\right)^{n}\bigg)
  \\\\&=-\frac{i}{\sqrt 7}\bigg((1+i\sqrt 7)^n-(1-i\sqrt 7)^n\bigg)-\bigg((1+i\sqrt 7)^n+(1-i\sqrt 7)^n\bigg)
  \\\\&=-\frac{i}{\sqrt 7}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom nj\bigg((i\sqrt 7)^j-(-i\sqrt 7)^j\bigg)-\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom nj\bigg((i\sqrt 7)^j+(-i\sqrt 7)^j\bigg)
  \\\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{(n+1)/2}\binom n{2k-1}2(-1)^{k+1}7^{k-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2}\binom n{2k}2(-1)^{k+1}7^k\end{align}$$
  Since $\binom{n}{m}\equiv 0\pmod n$ for $1\le m\le n-1$, we have
  $$\begin{align}2^{n+2}S_{\delta(n)}&\equiv 2(-1)^{(n+3)/2}7^{(n-1)/2}-2\pmod n
  \\\\&\equiv 2(-1)^{(n+3)/2}\frac{(-1)^{3(n-1)/2}}{\left(\frac n7\right)}-2\pmod n
  \\\\&\equiv 2(-1)^{2n}-2\pmod n
  \\\\&\equiv 0\pmod n\end{align}$$from which we get
  $$2^{n+2}S_{\delta(n)}\equiv 0\pmod n$$It follows from $\gcd(2^{n+2},n)=1$ that
  $$S_{\delta(n)}\equiv 0\pmod n$$
- **Case 3** : $n$ is a prime satisfying either $n\equiv 3,5$ or $6\pmod 7$
  Since $\left(\frac n7\right)=-1$, we get
  $$\bigg(\frac{-28}{n}\bigg)=\bigg(\frac{-1}{n}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{2^2}{n}\bigg)\bigg(\frac 7n\bigg)=(-1)^{(n-1)/2}\cdot 1\cdot \frac{(-1)^{3(n-1)/2}}{\left(\frac n7\right)}=-1$$So, we have, using $(1)$,
  $$\begin{align}2^{n+1}S_{\delta(n)}&=2^{n+1}S_{n+1}
  \\\\&=\frac{i}{\sqrt 7} \bigg((1-i\sqrt 7)\left(1-i\sqrt{7}\right)^{n}-(1+i\sqrt 7)\left(1+i\sqrt{7}\right)^{n}\bigg)
  \\\\&=-\frac{i}{\sqrt 7}\bigg((1+i\sqrt 7)^n-(1-i\sqrt 7)^n\bigg)+\bigg((1+i\sqrt 7)^n+(1-i\sqrt 7)^n\bigg)
  \\\\&=-\frac{i}{\sqrt 7}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom nj\bigg((i\sqrt 7)^j-(-i\sqrt 7)^j\bigg)+\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom nj\bigg((i\sqrt 7)^j+(-i\sqrt 7)^j\bigg)
  \\\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{(n+1)/2}\binom{n}{2k-1}2(-1)^{k+1}7^{k-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2}\binom{n}{2k}2(-1)^{k}7^k
  \\\\&\equiv 2(-1)^{(n+3)/2}7^{(n-1)/2}+2\pmod n
  \\\\&\equiv 2(-1)^{(n+3)/2}\frac{(-1)^{3(n-1)/2}}{\left(\frac n7\right)}+2\pmod n
  \\\\&\equiv 2(-1)^{2n+1}+2\pmod n
  \\\\&\equiv 0\pmod n\end{align}$$from which we get
  $$2^{n+1}S_{\delta(n)}\equiv 0\pmod n$$It follows from $\gcd(2^{n+1},n)=1$ that
  $$S_{\delta(n)}\equiv 0\pmod n$$

From the three cases above, the claim follows.$\quad\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

The roots of $x^3-2x^2+3x-2=0$ are ${1, \frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}, \frac{1-\sqrt{-7}}{2}}$
Let $\alpha = \frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2},\quad \beta = \frac{1-\sqrt{-7}}{2}$

Thus, the formula can be written as $S_n = A\cdot1^n + B\cdot\alpha^n + C\cdot\beta^n$ with $A,B,C.$
We can determine (A,B,C) using $S_0,S_1,S_2$ below

$A = \frac{-(\beta-1+\alpha)}{(-1+\beta)(-1+\alpha)}=0$
$B = \frac{\beta}{-\beta+\beta\alpha+\alpha-\alpha^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-7}}$
$C = \frac{-\alpha}{(-\alpha+\beta)(-1+\beta)}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{-7}}$

Hence we get $S_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-7}}((\frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2})^n-(\frac{1-\sqrt{-7}}{2})^n)$
Let $p$ be an odd prime.

\begin{align}
S_{p+1} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{-7}} \left(\middle(\frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}\middle)^{p+1}-\middle(\frac{1-\sqrt{-7}}{2}\middle)^{p+1} \right)\\  
&= \frac{1}{2^{p+1}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{-7}} \left(\middle(1+\sqrt{-7}\middle)^{p}\middle(1+\sqrt{-7}\middle)-\middle(1-\sqrt{-7}\middle)^{p}\middle(1-\sqrt{-7}\middle)\right)\\  
\end{align}
Since coefficients $\binom{p}{k}$ with $1\leqq k \leqq p-1$ are divisible by $p$, then we get,

$2^{p}S_{p+1}\equiv(-7)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1 \pmod{p}$

Using $(-7)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv ({\frac{-7}{p}}) \pmod{p},$ then

$2^{p}S_{p+1}\equiv({\frac{-7}{p}})+1 \pmod{p}$

Hence if $({\frac{-7}{p}})=-1$ then $S_{p+1} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$
$$ $$
$$ $$
$$ $$

\begin{align}
S_{p-1} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{-7}} \left(\middle(\frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}\middle)^{p-1}-\middle(\frac{1-\sqrt{-7}}{2}\middle)^{p-1} \right)\\  
&= \frac{1}{2^{p-1}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{-7}} \left(\middle(1+\sqrt{-7}\middle)^{p}\middle(1+\sqrt{-7}\middle)^{-1}-\middle(1-\sqrt{-7}\middle)^{p}\middle(1-\sqrt{-7}\middle)^{-1}\right)\\  
\end{align}

Since $(1+\sqrt{-7})^{-1}=(1-\sqrt{-7}/8$, $(1-\sqrt{-7})^{-1}=(1+\sqrt{-7}/8$, we get
$2^{p+1}S_{p-1}\equiv(-7)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1 \pmod{p}$

Using $(-7)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv ({\frac{-7}{p}}) \pmod{p},$ then $2^{p+1}S_{p-1}\equiv({\frac{-7}{p}})-1 \pmod{p}$

Hence if $({\frac{-7}{p}})=1$ then $S_{p-1} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$